# Run a custom command in Ubuntu using Java

Tags: java, shell, command

How to run a custom command (`Example: cryptogen generate --config=crypto-config.yaml`) through Java in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have tried Runtime.getRuntime().exec. However it recognizes only System commands such as "echo".

Comment: how is "cryptogen generate --config=crypto-config.yaml" a java command?

Comment: it is a custom Terminal command. I want to run it through a java program.

Comment: *"However it recognizes only System commands such as `echo`."*  - Probably because `cryptogen` is not on the search path when the JVM is launched.  Use the absolute path for the command instead.

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c Thanks for the tip :) That helped me.